# find all columns in data.frame with non leading NA values

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, na

```
             AA    AFGE
2015-09-30    NA 22.9170
2015-12-31    NA 23.1427
2016-03-31    NA 23.9825
2016-06-30    NA 24.6085
2016-09-30    NA 25.0717
2016-12-31 28.08 23.5920
2017-03-31 34.40 25.0819
2017-06-30 32.65 26.1776
2017-09-30 46.62 25.8541
2017-12-31 53.87 26.2200
2018-03-31 44.96 25.8608
2018-06-30 46.88 25.8300
2018-09-30 40.40 25.2347
2018-12-31 26.58 25.3200
2019-03-31 28.16 25.5000
2019-06-30 23.41 25.7900
2019-09-30 20.07 25.3400
2019-12-31 21.51 25.3600
2020-03-31  6.16      NA
2020-06-30 11.24      NA
2020-09-30 11.63 27.2300
```

I have a dataframe with 6000 columns and most of them have leading NA values like AA in the example. But I want to find all columns that have non-leading NA values (leading NA values or not that important), see AFGE with NA values for row 2020-03-31 & 2020-06-30.

If i can get all column(names) with non-leading NA values that would be great, but I would be better if I have a dataframe with TRUE/FALSE for non-leading NA values.
So in this case the dataframe would be FALSE for every value except for the two NA-values of AFGE in row 2020-03-31 & 2020-06-30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need something like this ?

```
sapply(df, function(x) {
  with(rle(is.na(x)), rep(values & seq_along(values) != 1, lengths))
})

#         AA  AFGE
# [1,] FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE
# [6,] FALSE FALSE
# [7,] FALSE FALSE
# [8,] FALSE FALSE
# [9,] FALSE FALSE
#[10,] FALSE FALSE
#[11,] FALSE FALSE
#[12,] FALSE FALSE
#[13,] FALSE FALSE
#[14,] FALSE FALSE
#[15,] FALSE FALSE
#[16,] FALSE FALSE
#[17,] FALSE FALSE
#[18,] FALSE FALSE
#[19,] FALSE  TRUE
#[20,] FALSE  TRUE
#[21,] FALSE FALSE
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(AA = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 28.08, 34.4, 32.65, 
46.62, 53.87, 44.96, 46.88, 40.4, 26.58, 28.16, 23.41, 20.07, 
21.51, 6.16, 11.24, 11.63), AFGE = c(22.917, 23.1427, 23.9825, 
24.6085, 25.0717, 23.592, 25.0819, 26.1776, 25.8541, 26.22, 25.8608, 
25.83, 25.2347, 25.32, 25.5, 25.79, 25.34, 25.36, NA, NA, 27.23
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2015-09-30", "2015-12-31", 
"2016-03-31", "2016-06-30", "2016-09-30", "2016-12-31", "2017-03-31", 
"2017-06-30", "2017-09-30", "2017-12-31", "2018-03-31", "2018-06-30", 
"2018-09-30", "2018-12-31", "2019-03-31", "2019-06-30", "2019-09-30", 
"2019-12-31", "2020-03-31", "2020-06-30", "2020-09-30"))
```

Comment: Almost! 
There are also columns where the first items are NA and there are non leading NA's, then I like to find the non leading NA's also in these columns.
So in this example if you change the 22.917 in AFGE (first item) in NA, I want to find the 2 NA's in the column that are non leading, now I don't find them for these kind of columns.

Comment: @gilberke The updated answer should work for such cases.